# How to access a DOM object and modify its properties using node.js?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to access an HTML `label` element and change its text property. I have already tried by using this code:

```
$('#label1').text('test');
```

However, I am getting error:

> $ is not defined.

Comment: node js is a backend technology you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js is used in back end side.
If you need to run your sample code, you must use some template engine like ejs to render HTML and include CSS, JavaScript.